# To what extent can atoms be *specularly* reflected (in the context of high velocities in a rarified atmosphere)?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, atomic-physics, reflection, drag, aerodynamics

This is a follow up to earlier comments below [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/55006/14419) regarding orbits at low altitude. The suggestion is to try to obtain energy from the Earth's rotation to maintain an orbit with a very low perigiee over the equator. This is to be achieved using a flat plate and specular reflection at a very shallow angle of the rarified atmosphere. My question is: can anything close to specular reflection be achieved with real materials and gas velocities of ~8 km/s?

I'm guessing that it's difficult to find a material with a sufficiently smooth surface and one that would not be quickly damaged by high velocity oxygen and ozone (single-crystal alumina?).

Maybe the very shallow angle (~2 degrees) of reflection would be helpful? Is there some analogy here with [grazing incidence mirrors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-ray_optics) used in telescopes for high-energy x-rays?